# PDF stuck in "printing" state using Java PDFBox 2.0.21

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox, printers

I am trying to setup a printer class in Java that can print PDF files using PDFBox.
My printPdf method successfully adds the .pdf file in the printer's queue but it does not print at all (it gets stuck in the "printing..." state).

It only happens to some specific PDF files. For some pdf files it will work perfectly, for some the issue will happen.

Here is the code I used to print the pdf files:

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Java Printing.pdf");
FilePrinter.printPdf(file, "Printer name");
```

FilePrinter.printPdf method:

```
public static void printPdf(File pdfFile, String laserName)
{
    PDDocument document = null;
    try {
        PrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        attr.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
        attr.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
        document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);

        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        PrintService myPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        for (PrintService printer : printServices) {
            if (printer.getName().equals(laserName))
                myPrintService = printer;
        }

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
        job.setPrintService(myPrintService);

        job.print(attr);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if(document != null) {
            try {
                document.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The pdf file I'm trying to print has 2 pages (It's not corrupted I can open it in any web browser), but in the file properties in the printer queue, it shows that the file size is 0 and has 0 page (cf next picture)

[File properties inside the printer's queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG9pj.png)

[Printer's queue status when I try to print the PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbWpF.png)

Is this issue related to PDFBox? To my printer? If I try printing it from my web browser it works like a charm but I really can't print it with java.

Comment: Probably transparency, which results in very slow printing. Try changing the `PDFPageable` construction so that the "dpi" parameter is an actual dpi value, e.g. 300 or 600. Please share your PDF if possible.

Comment: See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3046 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4942

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TilmanHausherr. I've tried using the PDFPageable constructor with different DPI values. Unfortunately, it still gets stuck in the printing spool.
I cannot share the pdf because it contains very sensitive data. All I can say is that it's made of scanned documents.

Comment: The printing spool problem is mentioned here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3729 it mentions a setting that may or may not make a difference.

Comment: Can the file be displayed with the PDFBox PDFDebugger application? I'm wondering whether this is a specific printing problem, or a rendering problem.

Comment: The "Enable Advance Printing features" option is correctly enabled in the printer's settings.
The file can be displayed with the PDFDebugger application, however when I try to print it from the PDFDebugger application, the same problem happens again.

Comment: You could try getting a similar, non-confidential PDF. Other ideas: update printer driver; try printing on a different printer (e.g. to XPS).

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I finally managed to make it work by fully uninstalling - reinstalling the printer's drivers (windows was wrong when telling me they were up to date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed after fully uninstalling and reinstalling the printer's drivers. Windows was wrong when it was telling me they were up to date !